# C++ to Delphi Header file translation: function with pointer to void

Tags: c++, delphi, header-files, delphi-xe4

I have trouble translating a c++ header file. When I execute my Delphi code it returns code 125 which stands for 'invalid parameters'. I'll explain what I've done so far:

The header file (fragment):

```
IDSEXP is_AOI(HIDS hCam, UINT nCommand, void *pParam, UINT SizeOfParam);
```

My translation:

```
function is_AOI(hCam: Cardinal; Command: Cardinal; Param: Pointer; ParamSize: Cardinal): integer; cdecl; external 'ueye_api.dll';
```

Example c++ code:

```
IS_SIZE_2D imageSize;
imageSize.s32Width = m_nSizeX;
imageSize.s32Height = m_nSizeY;
is_AOI(m_hCam, IS_AOI_IMAGE_SET_SIZE, (void*)&imageSize, sizeof(imageSize));
```

My code:

```
var
  size2D: TSize2D;

size2D.S32X := maxWidth;
size2D.S32Y := maxHeight;
ret := is_AOI(cam, IS_AOI_IMAGE_SET_SIZE, Pointer(@size2D), SizeOf(size2D));
```

The c++ struct:

```
typedef struct 
{
    INT s32Width;
    INT s32Height;
} IS_SIZE_2D;
```

And my translation:

```
TSize2D = record
  S32X, S32Y: integer;
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the translation to `pointer` is correct, I usually find it more elegant to replace a `*void` with an untyped `var` parameter.

`hCam` is a Handle, which is really a pointer; you should use `NativeUint` or `UIntPtr` for that or the code will break in 64-bit. Note that `THandle` is only appropriate for Windows API calls and this is a Google dll.

**Delphi 7 warning**
[Delphi 7 seems to think that `SizeOf(NativeUInt) = 8`,](http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.rtl/201104/1104134903.html) this is fixed in D2009 You can fix that by

```
{$IFNDEF VER200}  //anything prior to Delphi 2009
type
  NativeUInt = Cardinal;
  NativeInt = Integer;
{$ENDIF}
```

`IDSEXP` is defined as follows:
Note that the calling convention is only `cdecl` in 32 bit. In 64 bit the default Win64 calling convention is used.

```
#if defined __i386__
        #define IDSEXP    __attribute__((cdecl)) INT
        #define IDSEXPUL  __attribute__((cdecl)) ULONG
#else
        #define IDSEXP    INT
        #define IDSEXPUL  ULONG
#endif
```

However as per @David's comment x64 ignores calling convention keywords *because there is only one*, so the definition should look like:

```
function is_AOI(hCam: NativeUInt; 
                Command: Cardinal; 
                var Param; 
                ParamSize: Cardinal): integer; 
                cdecl; external 'ueye_api.dll';
```

You can now call it like so:

```
ret:= is_AOI(cam, IS_AOI_IMAGE_SET_SIZE, size2D, SizeOf(size2D));
```

**What's really causing your function to fail**
At first I thought that error 125 was a runtime error, but it's actually a return value from the function.
The fact that the function can be called and return a value means that the signature of your function is fine.
You are either supplying an invalid handle, or your Size2D parameters are out of range. 
Because you are passing `maxint`, I think you're pushing your luck here.

Pass something more reasonable in `Size2D`.

```
size2D.S32X := 100;
size2D.S32Y := 100;
ret := is_AOI(cam, IS_AOI_IMAGE_SET_SIZE, size2D, SizeOf(size2D));
```

Comment: I made the changes, but still am getting 125. It is a 32 bit application.

Comment: It works! I also had to change the order in which I called other functions. Thank you.

Comment: @johan The code in the question is accurate. Why do you think that `void*` does not map to `Pointer`?

Comment: So, how does this deal with the question. Also your understanding of calling conventions is not quite right. Or perhaps your explanation is weak. In x64 there is only one calling convention. And so `cdecl`, `stdcall` etc. are just ignored. The idiom is to include `cdecl` for targeting x86, and let the x64 compiler ignore it. In some logical sense, the function's calling convention really is `cdecl`, but it just so happens that on x64 that is implemented identically to all other conventions.

Comment: It does map to pointer, the `var` is just more elegant, Note I said "You can replace a *void with an untyped var parameter.", not you should or you must. I've disambiguified the first line.

Comment: The advice to use `THandle` is unsound. Please retract that. `THandle` is an operating system type that maps to the Windows `HANDLE` type. Variables of type `THandle` can be passed to Win32 API functions like `CloseHandle`. Using `THandle` gives the impression that the variable is an OS handle and so can be inherited, needs to be closed with `CloseHandle`, and so on. Use `UIntPtr`.

Comment: About x64: `the function's calling convention really is cdecl, but it just so happens that on x64 that is implemented identically to all other conventions.` That I did not realize, The real answer is under the edit; did you see that part?

Comment: Agreed an the THandle:it does give the impression of a WinAPI handle with all the care and nurturing that that implies.

Comment: OK, the answer is better now. I've looked at the edit history. Take a look at your first revision. It seems pretty clear that you were advocating replacing pointer with var param. Anyway, you can do it either way. If you use a var param, it's a little more tricky to pass `nil`.

Comment: So, good work on your edits. You've got an excellent attitude!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your existing code is a perfectly adequate translation of the native code. In C++, `void*` is an untyped pointer. The equivalent type in Delphi is `Pointer`. In other words you have already translated that parameter correctly.

The only thing that I can find incorrect is that `HIDS` is probably a pointer sized integer. And so it should probably be declared as `UIntPtr`, if you are using a modern Delphi that supports that type. However, I expect your code is 32 bit and so this is probably a non-issue for you.

So the conclusion is that your header translation is adequate, and that you are indeed passing invalid parameters. The solution to your problem will require you to study the library's documentation and make sure you are calling all the required functions in the right order, with the correct parameters.

Comment: The parameters were the primary problem indeed, however, using UIntPtr (at first THandle) instead of Cardinal for HIDS seemed to help with other functions of the same header file also. 
And using untyped var instead of Pointer made the code better to read. 
In any case: this problem has been solved!

Comment: If you code is 32 bit then UIntPtr is the same as Cardinal. Untyped parameter is also fine. Messy if you need to pass nil.